# Place Intervals to Maximize Number of Adjacency

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

**My problem:** 
I have n "items" to place on an integer axis. Each item contains several choices of placement, represented as closed intervals of integers. These intervals can have some overlapping elements. The goal is to find a non-overlapping placement (if any) of the n items on the int axis with maximal number of interval adjacency.

**More details with the terms used above:**
1) Overlapping: interval [1, 4] and [3, 6] have two overlapping elements {3} and {4}; interval [2, 5] and [6, 10] do not overlap.
2) Interval adjacency: interval [a, b] and [b+1, c] are called adjacent. The number of interval adjacency for this example is 1. The maximal possible number of interval adjacency for n items is n-1, which occurs when the placement makes n intervals pair-wisely adjacent.

**Example:**
There are 3 items; their placement choices are listed here

```
item1 has 2 choices: [1, 4], [2, 5]
item2 has 3 choices: [5, 8], [9, 11], [16, 18]
item3 has 2 choices: [3, 5], [13, 15]
```

One feasible  placement is

```
[1, 4](item1), [5, 8](item2), [13, 15](item3)
```

Another two feasible  placement are

`[1, 4](item1), [16, 18](item2), [13, 15](item3);` and

```
[2, 5](item1), [16, 18](item2), [13, 15](item3).
```

All these three placement in this example are optimal. The number of interval adjacency is 1.

**My question:**
Is there a better way than enumeration of all possibilities? 
I can only think of that if an interval choice of an item overlaps with all the choices of another item, then this choice can be excluded. Any ideas are welcome:)

Comment: The answer depends on a lot of things. Could you give us some constraints like what's the maximum number of items and intervals?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei I'm tending to find a general solution since the constraints can get really loose...Anyway, the maximum number of items and intervals (for each item) can be restricted to 20 and 200,000 respectively. The int axis can be restricted to [1, 2^20].

Comment: This problem is strongly NP-hard (reduction sketch: from 3-CNF-SAT, item for each variable and clause, two choices per variable item and three per clause item), but you're in luck: whoever posed the problem was very stingy with the item limit. I'll let someone else post the DP.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Are you talking about the (2 ^ n) * numOfAllIntervalsForItems algorithm?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei Something like that.